# gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

Tags: linux, password, gpg

Пытаюсь расшифровать пароли в pass с помощью gpg(зашифрованы они были тоже с gpg) на новой системе с новым юзером. Раздел с /home я не форматировал, чтобы оставить все нужное(конфиги, пароли, .gnupg, .password-store и т.д.).

Был такой файл: ~/.password-store/.gpg-id. Предварительно скопировав .gnupg с бекапа в ~/ и использовав команду **sudo chown -R leo:staff ~/.gnupg** (leo это юзер на новой системе, на которой я щас сижу), сделал следующее, использовав содержимое файла .gpg-id(3D8ABF94A4E38339):

- $ gpg --export 3D8ABF94A4E38339 > pub.key
- $ gpg --export-secret-keys 3D8ABF94A4E38339 > sec.key
- **gpg: key 3D8ABF94A4E38339/82E95B5A6D369E55: error getting keyinfo from agent: Invalid argument - skipped**
- $ gpg --import pub.key
- gpg: key 3D8ABF94A4E38339: "Leonid " not changed
- gpg: Total number processed: 1
- gpg:              unchanged: 1
- $ gpg --import sec.key
- gpg: key 3D8ABF94A4E38339: "Leonid " not changed
- gpg: key 3D8ABF94A4E38339: secret key imported
- gpg: Total number processed: 1
- gpg:              unchanged: 1
- gpg:       secret keys read: 1
- gpg:  secret keys unchanged: 1
- $ pass -c social/spotify
- **gpg: decryption failed: No secret key**

---

Не знаю что означает третья строчка сверху вниз, но мне кажется, что она важная, и в ней кроется вся проблема. Я думаю, что проблема с секретным ключом, т.к он необходим для дешифовки. Шифруя какой-то файл(с опцией --recipient 3D8ABF94A4E38339), я не вижу никаких ошибок(тут используется public, значит с ним все ок), а дешифруя(с той же опцией) его же вылезает последняя строчка.

Я думаю, что моя ошибка в том, что я использую неправильный секретный ключ(да, мои догадки странные), но, чтобы в этом убедиться полностью, мне нужно знать, какой секретный ключ принадлежит к конкретному зашифрованному файлу(скорее всего, понятия "принадлежность" здесь не существует, хотя, мб, я ошибаюсь), хотя бы id знать, к какому секретному ключу он обращается. Но, с другой стороны, id ключа(.gpg-id) итак есть в директории .password-store. BTW, при экспорте секрет ключа мне нужно было ввести passphrase. Именно этот passphrase я использовал ранее на другой системе для доступа к своим паролям. То есть, это знак того, что я вроде бы экспортировал правильный secret key.

---

Вообщем я не знаю, что мне делать. У меня есть нетронутый бекап со всеми файлами, конфигами и т.д, но я не знаю как мне всем этим правильно воспользоваться. Помогите, пожалуйста